# xCode9 not showing UIControls' any property in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode9

I am facing a strange issue on `xCode9` and that is my any of UIControls which I drop on storyboard viewcontroller scene does not appear properly.

Neither of it's title text, background color, or anything. Also when I drag and drop the control, it's height and width automatically becomes 0.

I have tried

- Every possible options
- different size classes
- Editor > Canvas > Bound rectangles show/hide
- Quit the xCode, removed derived data etc.

But not succeed by trying any solution.

[image: Here is .gif for better understanding of issue]

Comment: could you try re-open xCode and open a xib file and do so.

Comment: @NFLee, yes as I mentioned Quit the xCode, removed derived data etc. I have tried

Comment: I mean instead of drag a button in to storyboard but a xib.

Comment: @NFLee, yes, same problem persists in .xib as well as .storyboard. I tried that in new project also but same happens.